# The subjunctive in a hypothetical scenario of a historical event

Tags: grammar, word-usage, past-tense, conditionals, subjunctive-mood

To the prompt "What historical moment would you like to have participated in?", my ESL student chose a Queen Live Aid concert, saying:

> I’m a huge fan of Queen and Freddie Mercury so I think that I would
> totally cry all concert long. When the piano **[to start]** playing
> Bohemian Rhapsody, I would get goosebumps.

Since English doesn't seem to have a pure subjunctive form, I can't seem to find a solution to the verb 'to start'. I've asked around and got too many different answers.

Are any of these correct?

1. When the piano starts, I would get goosebumps.
2. When the piano would start, I would get goosebumps.
3. When the piano started, I would get goosebumps.
4. As soon as the piano started, I would get goosebumps.

Comment: Since this is imaginary context, use imaginary grammar. I.e, if you're making it up the way you like, use whatever grammar you like.

Comment: Isn't there something to be said about what sounds natural to the ears, though?

Comment: If you're writing, the ears are not involved.

Comment: "When the piano hypothetically started playing Bohemian Rhapsody, I would get goosebumps." is fine. Although you can use the historic present as long as you can convince the reader it's deliberate and not a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Either (3) or (4) would be fine.

*Starts* doesn't go with *would cry* in the previous sentence. *Would start* sounds like a habitual action.

Comment: It is "habitual" in the sense that the past would be repeating itself, only on this occasion with the fan in attendance.  The fan is anticipating the past playing out again.

Comment: @Tim - But *when the piano starts* is a singular anticipated/expected (indicative) instance, so the result clause can't mean multiple instances. You would have to use whenever instaed to get that meaning. Still nothing subjunctive about it.

Comment: @UbuEnglish "When the sun rises..." can refer to the upcoming sunrise or to  every (usual/habitual) sunrise.  When the sun rises we will attack the citadel.  When the sun rises the cock crows.   Same is true of "when the music starts".  The original question is about a stage performance which has certain set pieces in it, and that admits the usual/habitual sense.

Comment: Yes. It's interesting how the variable interpretations of the when clause are usually selected rather unambiguously by the complementary result clause.

Answer (score 2):

This is an imagined condition in the past which can never come to happen now. Normally, for such situations the third conditional is used:

> We use the third conditional when we imagine a different past, where something did or did not happen, and we imagine a different result:
>
> - If the weather ***had improved***, we ***could have gone*** for a walk. (*The weather did not improve – fine weather is therefore an **impossible** condition*.)([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if?q=conditional%20clauses))

You wish you could have been present at one of Queen's concerts, but this wish is now impossible. However, you imagine how it ***would have been***, if you ***had gone*** to such a concert. And you say:

> I’m a huge fan of Queen and Freddie Mercury so I think that ***[if I had been at one of their concerts]***, I ***would have totally cried*** all concert long. I ***would have gotten*** goosebumps as soon as the piano ***would have started*** playing Bohemian Rhapsody.

Having said all that, it is true that in this sentence the third conditional is wordy. And native speakers do have the tendency to use the second conditional to include impossible conditions.

Comment: I don't find "would have started playing" idiomatic.

Comment: In standard English, you generally don't use *would* in the main clause of conditionals. So apart from a large number of Americans who the rest of the world thinks speak ungrammatically, the way people would express this is *I would have gotten goosebumps as soon as the piano started playing Bohemian Rhapsody.* (Or *would have got* if you're British).

Comment: Yes, "as soon as the piano **started** playing".

Comment: At least you set the actual hypothetical condition correctly with the subjunctive *if* clause. And, yes, as soon as the piano started is the corrected form. But still none of the OG sentences use if or the subjunctive, they are all indictive with when as the conjunction. Maybe such constructions are 'conditional' but I have always presumed that conditionals require either the if form or the inverted form of the subjunctive.

Answer (score 1):

There's an understood if-clause:

- [*If I'd been at such a concert,*] *I'd have got goosebumps when / as soon as the piano started playing Bohemian Rhapsody.*

I'd say that this is the more likely deletion, but one can also argue for

- *I’m a huge fan of Queen and Freddie Mercury so I think that [if I were at such a concert,] I would totally cry all concert long. When / As soon as the piano started playing Bohemian Rhapsody, I would get goosebumps.*

This licences (3)/(4).

(2) while arguably grammatical, sounds unidiomatic or at least very formal/dated, and I think the argument that (1) is justified as an example of using the historic[al]/dramatic/narrative present is weak: consistency within the sentence requires 'The piano starts playing Bohemian Rhapsody, and I get goosebumps.'

Comment: Yes, but the OG is trying to get the subjunctive to work in an indicative when clause - is that even possible?

Comment: The subjunctive? That uses the bare form (the bare infinitive) of a verb. I don't see 'When the piano start' in any of OP's examples.

Comment: Right, because that was his question - which no one seems to be addressing. You can't use the subjunctive in an indicative when clause, at least that's what I think. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: Yes, 'When the piano were to start playing' is ungrammatical. But OP asks the question about which of the four sentences is acceptable: I'm not sure Ao sees 'subjunctive' as an inflection rather than a type of English sometimes used to describe hypothetical situations.. The hypothetical setting has already been established ['I would love to have been at a Queen Live Aid concert ...'] and the sentence 'When X happened within this framework, Y would also happen as a result' is correct.

Comment: Yes, I suppose, the question requires some interpretation. Ao is a teacher and the quoted text is a student's submission, which does not include a hypothetical subjunctive clause anywhere. So maybe that's what threw me off (I also teach). In any case, without a subjucntive clause somewhere, the indicative + modal sentences Ao, the teacher, is asking about take a different meaning than with a subjunctive main clause. Anyway, that seems describe what I'm observing. Ao tries to fit the subjunctive into result causes but it doesn't go there.

Answer (score 1):

> If I were able to travel back into the past in a time machine, I'd go
> back to a Queen concert. **I would get goosebumps when the piano
> started playing Bohemian Rhapsody**.

I can attest that the above is idiomatic American English.

The fan is imagining themselves present at a concert in the past, anticipating Bohemian Rhapsody, which is yet to come.

Comment: I would would *have got* goosebumps when the piano started playing Bohemian Rhapsody, if I had attended a Queen concert. Your sentence works because you already set the hypothetical in the first sentence. But alone, without that context the sentence wouldn't work. It would have to be I got goosebumps and maybe even with that context being set, I believe.

Comment: The OP's original question refers to a question (a prompt) that establishes the context.  But the sentence in bold in my answer (I would get .... Rhapsody) in the absence of any context could have different meanings. It could be said by an ardent fan or "groupie" who had attended many Queen concerts so that "when" would mean "whenever", and the fan would be referring to habitual behavior in the past. Or it could refer to an imaginary or hypothetical (How would you feel if you were to attend a Queen concert?)

Answer (score 1):

> When the piano [to start] playing Bohemian Rhapsody, I would get goosebumps.

When the piano **started** <s>playing</s> **to play** Bohemian Rhapsody, I would get goosebumps.

"When the piano started to play Bohemian Rhapsody," is a fronting adverbial clause - a free modifier. The use of "when" instead of "if" states that this event is inevitable, it would be wrong to use the subjunctive.

The tense and mood in adverbial clauses is not directly linked to the main clause as their purpose is to modify the verb effectively - whatever form the verb takes.

Comment: I don't see the difference between *playing* and *to play*. Both of these clause are indicative and I agree that it would be wrong to use the subjunctive, especially in the adverbial *when* clause but I think also in the result clause. It should be, *I got goosebumps*. for the almost same reason - it's indicative, or should be. If *whenever* were used you could say *get* but it would still be indicative.

Comment: So maybe I've been seeing this a little backwards. In your sentence, the modal is the main clause, past indicative, and the adverbial when clause, also indicative, is just saying when the main clause happens, hence adverbial. In the subjunctive conditional form, the subjunctive verb is the main clause, setting a hyothetical, and the modal is the dependent complement, stating a result.

Answer (score -1):

Are any of these correct? No, not really.

1. *When the piano starts, I would get goosebumps.
2. *When the piano would start, I would get goosebumps.
3. *When the piano started, I would get goosebumps.
4. *As soon as the piano started, I would get goosebumps.

Well, none of your clauses use the subjunctive, so they do not establish an imaginary instance of the verb (one that is only imagined to happen or to have already happened), which what John Lawler was pointing out. Other than that there are problems with all of these constructions. Others may disagree, but I think these constructions are all incorrect because the clauses do not reconcile with each other in time or tense usage. The clause, *I would get goosebumps,* especially when combined with a when-clause is interpreted as a past complete routine. *Would*, in this case, is interpreted as the past of *will*.

In the context you've provided the primary hypothetical idea is *the subject attending such an event*, which should use the subjunctive but you have excluded this in your sentences. Let's include it and see what happens:

[Were I to attend a Queen concert], [I would get goosebumps].

[imaginary: I have not attended]        [imaginary: dependent on the subjunctive clause]

The modal clause is dependent upon the subjunctive clause, so, it is also interpreted as imaginary. Let's add your when-clause to this sentence.

[Were I to attend a Queen concert], [I would get goosebumps (when the piano starts)].

[imaginary: I have not attended]        [imaginary: dependent]

Here, the added clause is just complementing the modal clause - it's interpretation is dependent on that clause, and they work together to complement the main subjunctive (imaginary) clause, *Were I to attend...*

So, if the main clause isn't imaginary (subjunctive), as in your sentences, neither are any other clauses, whether or not they have happened *yet*.

1. *I would get goosebumps when the piano starts

The main clause uses the modal *would*, and without a subjunctive clause in the sentence, in *I would get goosebumps,* *would* is interpreted as the past (of will). So, you've got a past clause in a relation with a present clause, and these timeframes don't reconcile. It's like saying:

[I got goosebumps] [when the piano starts].

(in the past) (as a routine in the present)

This is nonsensible because there is no coherent time relation between the clauses. The correct forms are:

I get goosebumps when(ever) the piano starts. (present routine)

I got goosebumps when the piano started. (past complete, one time)

I got goosebumps whenever the piano started. (past complete, routine)

I will get goosebumps when the piano starts. (future, unrealized)

The last sentence is about the future, so it must be imaginary and of course it is, but not in the same way as the subjunctive. In this case both clauses are indicative statements about the future - they are more like reliable predictions and are intended that way, rather than the subjunctive which imagines conditions and results, that are probable or improbable, and are used to express wishes, desires, regrets and so on about the past, present or future.

That should be enough for you to figure out why the rest of your sentences are broken. Just keep in mind that the interpretation of dependent clauses relies on the mood and tense of the main or higher clause for correct understanding.

Comment: My addtion to this thread has caused a flurry of new answers and comments but no one has had anything to say about this answer.

Comment: None of your suggestions works. Because this is an imaginary situation, you need a ***would*** — "I would get goosebumps when the piano started" or "I would have got goosebumps when the piano started." The second is probably slightly more correct grammatically, but English speakers often substitute the past for the past perfect.

Comment: I see what you're saying but the OP student's submission did not use the subjunctive to set a condition (Had I participated in a Queen concert...) and then Ao the teacher, seems to reset the primary hypothetical verb to *start*, and asks about how to set the subjunctive condition in what is actually an indicative clause starting with *when*. But *when* won't take the subjunctive (I think). The conditional uses the subjunctive, so, *Should the piano start* or *If the piano starts...* - The mood of the main clause determines the interpretation of the modal result clause. Modal follows mood.

Comment: The use of *would* for hypothetical situations is not restrictive to conditional sentences in English, despite what you may have learned in your casses.